# ¿Cual es mi ERROR? | netbeans + postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, netbeans

Disculpen la desprolijidad, soy nuevo en el foro y estoy con por entregar un trabajo practico, me estoy volviendo loco con un problema en la conexión entre NetBeans y postgresql.

En el día de ayer probé algunas cosas y todo funcionaba a la perfección, pero en el día de hoy al abrir NetBeans no logro que me aparezca nada en consola, solo me figura.

> ```
> run:
> org.postgresql.Driver
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
> ```

¿A que se debe, que estoy haciendo mal? probé volviendo a colocar el Drive en otra carpeta, cree un proyecto nuevo, reinicie la conexión con sql, y nada funciona. Les agradecería mucho su ayuda!!.

```
    private static final String DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String URL_CONEXION = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ttm";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        final String usuario = "postgres";
        final String password = "admin";
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_CONEXION, usuario, password);
            String selectTableSQL = "SELECT nombre,preferencia,presupuesto,tiempo_disp FROM usuario";
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String nomb = rs.getString("nombre");
                String pref = rs.getString("preferencia");
                String pres = rs.getString("presupuesto");
                String time = rs.getString("tiempo_disp");
                System.out.println("> Nombre: " + nomb);
                System.out.println("> Preferencia: " + pref);
                System.out.println("> Presupuesto: $" + pres);
                System.out.println("> Tiempo disponible: " + time
                        + " Horas\n__________________________________\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Idea que no debe usarse en producción: poner en el catch que atrape Exception (la madre de todas las excepciones) y que pinte lo que sea que esté pasando :)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de JDBC estás usando? Me parece que en las últimas versiones ya no es necesario usar `Class.forName`

Comment: estoy utilizando postgresql-42.2.18, pero el problema es que ayer funcionaba como corresponde pero hoy sin ningún cambio en el codigo dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Intenta conectar sin usar `Class.forName`, [con un código parecido al indicado aquí](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html). Y si no funciona dinos qué es lo que no funciona. El mensaje dice `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, lo cual indica que no ha habido error al compilar el código. A veces es bueno hacer un Rebuild o un Clean and Build.

Comment: Intenta  esto: `Properties props = new Properties(); props.setProperty("user","postgres"); props.setProperty("password","admin"); Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_CONEXION, props);` y comenta esta línea: `//Class.forName(DRIVER);`

Comment: me aparece 
**run:
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ttm
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)**